# open save and close text file with vbs (access)

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

The questions is how to open save and close a textfile from vbscript.

I need to open a specific txt file, save it and then close the text file.

I can open a file with:

```
Dim Objecttxt
Set Objecttxt = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Objecttxt.Run "notepad.exe d:\text.txt"
```

and then i try to command the txt file with:

```
Objecttxt.SendKeys "^(s)", True
```

and

```
Objecttxt.SendKeys "%({F4})", True
```

but the focus is not set to the notepad editor.

Also i add the line:
Objecttxt.AppActivate "Text.txt - Kladblok", 800
but it seems like ths has no infuence.
the command: WScript.Sleep 800 is not accepted (access 2007)

Can someone tell me:

- it this the right way
- how can this method work?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to save it if you're not making any changes to it?

Comment: I only want to open and save to give it the right format by save the file. I'am also try the command set ObjFile open and Close but then it only saved the file when something is changed.

Comment: you would help me a bunch if you accepted my answer

Answer (score 0):

For example I'm changing a .png file to .jpg

```
Option Explicit
' Change the Extension you want to Replace
Const CHANGE_FROM = ".png"
Const CHANGE_TO = ".jpg"

' Var Declaration - Don't Change
Dim srcFolder
Dim objFSO, objFolder, oFolder
Dim colFiles

' Set the Source Folder to Begin With or you can dynamically find this if this is being used on multiple computers
srcFolder = "C:\Temp\Files"

' Object Sets - Don't Change
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(srcFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

' Changes Files Extensions in Source Folder
ChangeExtension colFiles
' Change the Extension for Each Sub Folder in the Source Folder
GetFilesFromSubFolders objFolder
```

Description : Sub will Recursevlly Check each folder for sub folders
For Each Sub folder it will Extract the Files and Use the ChangeExtension
to change the files Extension
Input  : Root Folder Object
Output : Recursive Call For Each Sub Folder - Change Files Extension

```
 --- Subs ---
 Sub GetFilesFromSubFolders(objRootFolder)
 Dim oSubFolders, oSubFol
 Dim colSubFolFiles
 ' Get the Sub Folders of the Root Folder
 Set oSubFolders = objRootFolder.SubFolders
 ' Check that Folder has Sub Folders
 If oSubFolders.Count > 0 Then
 ' For Each Sub Folder Call Recursevlly 
 For Each oSubFol In oSubFolders
 GetFilesFromSubFolders oSubFol
 Next 
 End If
 ' Get the Files in the folder
 Set colSubFolFiles = objRootFolder.Files 
 ' Change Files Extensions in Folder
 ChangeExtension colSubFolFiles
End Sub

Sub ChangeExtension(collectionSet)
' Description : Sub will Change the Extension 
' for Each File that has the Requested Extension
' Input  : Collection Set Object of Files
' Output : Changes the File Extension
Dim objFile
 ' For Each File in the Files Collection
 For Each objFile In collectionSet
 ' Check if File has the Requested Extension
 If InStr(objFile.Name,CHANGE_FROM) Then
 ' Checge the Extension
 objFile.Name = Replace(objFile.Name,CHANGE_FROM,CHANGE_TO)
 End If
 Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: code:

Dim strMCP1Name As String
Dim ObjFso As Object
Dim ObjFile As Object

strMCP1Name = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & location & "\tst.csv"


Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ObjFile = ObjFso.OpenTextFile(strMCP1Name, 8, -1) 'Opening the file Set


'ObjFile.WriteLine (";") 'Writing some data into the file


ObjFile.Close 'Closing the file
-------------

The problem is when i add a line to the file the close command is also the save command.

when i remove the line add command, nothing is changed in the file and therefor the file close command don't save the file.

Comment: thanks for replay, i had noy enoug characters.  therefore here is the rest of the comment.

So what I need is a command "save"


So the name and the data in the file must remain the same.
Only by saving the file the format of the data is set the the right format.

Comment: Why do you need to run a command to get this done? if all you want to do is change the extension on a file this code will work.